# FMDB Database Query IOS FIND_IN_SET()

Tags: ios, sql, fmdb, find-in-set

I am using FMDB database in IOS. In my database I have a one column called tags.
Tags column have a comma separated Value like `apple,banana,`. I want `Title` column where my keyword matches. I want to know how to search comma separated value in table column Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`LIKE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9008682/4519059) operator, when you have a field data like `apple,banana,...` you can add a `,` at the beginning  and end of it like `,apple,banana,...,` that makes all tags between two commas. Now you can check it if it contains `,yourTag,`.

I'm not so familiar with FMDB, But I think below code can help you:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT Title FROM yourTable WHERE ','+tags+',' LIKE ?",
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", @"," + search_text + @","]];
```

Comment: @viratpuar You can check the link for [`Like`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9008682/4519059) and edit it as I described to achieve what you want ;).

Comment: Thanks i get what i want ;)